# Embed interactive Google Map in email

Tags: google-maps, email, embed

Is it possible to embed an interactive Google Map in an email?

I know it is possible with static maps, but I'm starting to doubt if it is possible with interactive ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

I don't even know whether the map uses Javascript, Flash, Java, HTML5, or anything else, but I can still confidently say 'no'.

There's virtually no chance that your recipient's mail client will support it.

You might come across some mail clients (most likely webmails) that haven't blocked that kind of content, but that will almost certainly be an oversight on their part.
No decent mail software is going to support it, because the technologies involved are either complex or a security risk to the end user.

And even if some newer mail clients were to somehow provide support for it, you need to consider that many people have old email clients. It's commonly said that you [have to design emails like it's 1999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136002/what-version-of-html-to-use-in-emails#comment11483407_9136002).

The best you will be able to do is include a link in your message, to a hosted map.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for your reply. Best regards. Federico.